# Guardar imagen laravel

Tags: php, laravel, imagen, post, storage

Tengo un problema con mi metodo Store de Laravel.

Estoy recibiendo una imagen de tipo file, en PHP recibo algo asi...

```
C:\xampp\tmp\php8236.tmp
```

Esto se supone que es un archivo temporal, lo que quiero es llevar este archivo a la ruta

```
Public/Storage/usuarios/MI_IMAGEN
```

Normalmente lo haria con el metodo Store

```
$imagenFachada = $request->file('imagen')->store('usuarios/');
```

Pero el anterior programador modifico algo en las rutas porque ahora si hago eso, guarda la imagen en

```
Storage/App/Public/Usuarios/MI_IMAGEN
```

No se que cambio habra hecho, creo que tiene algo que ver con el file name pero no tengo ni idea. Ayuda... llevo horas con esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que tiene algo que ver son las rutas del archivo config/fileSystem

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: mmm irreproducible ..

Comment: Es muy difícil reproducirlo, tendría que cargar todo el proyecto. No sé qué demonios hicieron con el código.

Comment: nosotros menos XD